# create a list from given data to use in read_fwf

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

in load_fwf the parameter colspecs assigned as a list like this example

```
data2 = pd.read_fwf("sample.txt",index_col='Order number',names=['Order number', 'code', 'valid(1)/not-valid(0) transactions','Short description','long description'], engine='python', colspecs=[(0,5),(6,13),(14,15),(16,76),(77,400)], header=None)
```

so I  have a data of set number positional width of each column
like (example)

```
 ____________________________________________
 |position|length|column name               |
 |1       |5     |code                      |
 |6       |20    |short description         |
______________________________________________
```

so know how to code it so I could extract the data and create into list like this
**[(0,5),(6,20)]**

**additional information**

```
    Position    Length  Contents
0   1   5   Order number
1   6   1   Blank
2   7   7   code
3   14  1   Blank
4   15  1   valid(1)/not-valid(0) transactions
5   16  1   Blank
6   17  60  Short description
7   77  1   Blank
8   78  400 Long description
```

if I use your suggestion it will give the output like

```
[(1, 5),
 (6, 1),
 (7, 7),
 (14, 1),
 (15, 1),
 (16, 1),
 (17, 60),
 (77, 1),
 (78, 400)]
```

but I want
`[(1,5),(6,13),(14,15),(16,76),(77,400)]`

here i combined the blank to the next row in the table  but for this example I want it like this
​

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) for that:

```
import pandas as pd

data2 = pd.DataFrame({"position": [1, 6], "length": [5, 20], "column name": ["code", "short description"]})
print(data2)
#    position  length        column name
# 0         1       5               code
# 1         6      20  short description

data3 = list(zip(data2.position, data2.length))
print(data3)
# [(1, 5), (6, 20)]
```

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) returns an iterator. So if you just want to iterate over it later (e.g. in a for loop), you don't need to convert it to a list:

```
data4 = zip(data2.position, data2.length)
for x in data4:
   print(x)
# (1, 5)
# (6, 20)
```

**Edit:**

So with the blank lines and the irregularity in the last line, I would use a different approach:

```
colspecs = [
    (row["Position"], row["Position"] + row["Length"]) for i, row in data2.iterrows() if row["Contents"] != "Blank"
]

colspecs[-1] = (colspecs[-1][0], data2.Length.values[-1])
```

Comment: your suggestion is helpful but it is giving the list based on the given input what is the input is something like this (check the additional information added to the question)

Comment: Unfortunately, with the given information I can't figure out how the conversion from table to list is supposed to work. Please make sure that the numbers in your example are correct and add an explanation.

Comment: i the table is correct it contains the starting position of the column name and the size of the column is mentioned in the length
the output I said I wanted it like that, in the that I combine the blank with the next one in row

Comment: If you could describe "combine" in more detail, I might be able to help you. What operations exactly do you have in mind?

Comment: How do you get from (6,1,Blank)+(7,7,code) to  (6,13) in the same way you get from (14,1,Blank) + (15,1, ...) to (14,15)?

Comment: want to automate that part if it is manual  I  can set the list based on the info but I want to know if there is a possibility for automating it

Comment: what about:
`colspecs = [(row["Position"], row["Position"] + row["Length"]) for i, row in data2.iterrows() if row["Contents"] != "Blank"]` ?

Comment: `pos_code1=[(row["Position"], row["Position"] + row["Length"]) for i, row in data.iterrows() if row["Contents"] != "Blank"]`

Comment: can u explain what is iterrows() is  and what can I change to adjust the last one in the table case it should be 400 but it is 478

Comment: tried on the table it self answer `[(1, 6), (7, 14), (15, 16), (17, 77), (78, 478)]`

Comment: Are you sure you want 400 and not 478? [colspecs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) is defined as "A list of tuples giving the extents of the fixed-width fields of each line as half-open intervals (i.e., [from, to[ )." If your field starts at 78 and has a length of 400, the stop index should be 478, right?

Comment: 400 is overall length so it should stop there

Comment: how can the overall length of a line be 400 if the field with a length of 400 starts at index 78?

Comment: i meant length combined total of columns is 400

Comment: And what does that mean? Something other than each line in the file having a width of 400 characters?

Comment: maybe this example might help
`__________________________________________________________________________________________
 |order number(len=5)|code(len=7)|transaction(len=1)|short(len=60)|long(len=to end)|`
total length=400 for this example I changed it to 400 from to end in the table

Comment: yes the total characters in the data is 400

Comment: Ok, so that means the last row is treated differently from the others? In this case you could adjust `colspecs` like this:
`colspecs[-1] = (colspecs[-1][0], data2.Length.values[-1])`